# How to find tags only in current class?

Tags: java, vim, editor, ctags

I am using vim to do java programming. Feeling quite good until now.

But i have a question:
As we all know, we can use `:ta` to find the tag we specified.But every time i using this command, vim always search all the tags in my tags file. What i want now is just search the tags in current class. when i just input part of the tag name, and press <kbd>TAB</kbd>, it will only iterate tags under current class.

thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure VIM supports that. It's a text editor not an IDE and thus won't know about programming language specifics.

Comment: I have looked into tags file. There actually has a column to store which this tag belongs. So i guess it can be done.

Comment: @ccheng How did it go? Found anything useful?

Comment: @Johan `find tag` in vim will find the tag in current file first and the other file. If only want to find tag in current file, then i think you can open [java-browser](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=588) and then search in it. BTW, i switched to emacs.

Answer (score 0):

While it might be good to start with a text editor such as VIM and command line tools (javac,...) to learn the basics such as how to work with the classpath etc., I strongly recommend to use an IDE such as NetBeans or Eclipse as soon as you understand the basics.

Comment: My computer is not very faster. So after launching eclipse, android emulator, chrome with a few tabs, i almost can't do any thing now.